Polars struct.field(list[str]) returns a single column when dealing with list[Struct]
Some of my columns in my Polars Dataframe have the dtype pl.List(pl.Struct). I'm trying to replace these columns so that I get multiple columns that are lists of scalar values.
Here's an example of a column I'm trying to change:
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "column_0": [
        [{"field_1": "a", "field_2": 1}, {"field_1": "b", "field_2":2}],
        [{"field_1": "c", "field_2":3}]
    ]
})

col_name = "column_0"

df.select(
    pl.col(col_name).list.eval(
        pl.element().struct.unnest()
    )
)

My expectation was that I'll get something like this:
shape: (2, 2)
┌────────────┬───────────┐
│ field_1    ┆ field_2   │
│ ---        ┆ ---       │
│ list[str]  ┆ list[i64] │
╞════════════╪═══════════╡
│ ["a", "b"] ┆ [1, 2]    │
│ ["c"]      ┆ [3]       │
└────────────┴───────────┘

Instead, I only get the last field (in this case, 'field_2'):
shape: (2, 1)
┌───────────┐
│ column_0  │
│ ---       │
│ list[i64] │
╞═══════════╡
│ [1, 2]    │
│ [3]       │
└───────────┘


Thanks for adding the data, but the most useful form would be an executable code sample that sets up the dataframe without more setup.

A single .list.eval() will not produce multiple new columns - but that result looks odd. (Possibly a bug?) Do you know the number of fields in the struct? Or are you trying to do this "dynamically" for any number of fields?

I'm trying to do this dynamically. The number of fields in the struct varies by column.

You could unpack the lists/structs with .explode() + .unnest() and group the rows back together.
(df.with_row_index()
   .explode("column_0")
   .unnest("column_0")
   .group_by("index", maintain_order=True)
   .all()
)

shape: (2, 3)
┌───────┬────────────┬───────────┐
│ index ┆ field_1    ┆ field_2   │
│ ---   ┆ ---        ┆ ---       │
│ u32   ┆ list[str]  ┆ list[i64] │
╞═══════╪════════════╪═══════════╡
│ 0     ┆ ["a", "b"] ┆ [1, 2]    │
│ 1     ┆ ["c"]      ┆ [3]       │
└───────┴────────────┴───────────┘


Very nice solution avoiding any iteration.

You can access the field names through the pl.DataFrame.schema attribute  and create suitable expressions to create the list columns as follows.
df.with_columns(
    pl.col("column_0").list.eval(
        pl.element().struct.field(field.name)
    ).alias(field.name)
    for field in df.schema["column_0"].inner.fields
)

shape: (2, 3)
┌────────────────────┬────────────┬───────────┐
│ column_0           ┆ field_1    ┆ field_2   │
│ ---                ┆ ---        ┆ ---       │
│ list[struct[2]]    ┆ list[str]  ┆ list[i64] │
╞════════════════════╪════════════╪═══════════╡
│ [{"a",1}, {"b",2}] ┆ ["a", "b"] ┆ [1, 2]    │
│ [{"c",3}]          ┆ ["c"]      ┆ [3]       │
└────────────────────┴────────────┴───────────┘


Your solution works and is very helpful but is it possible to not use a for loop? Also, where did you find the attributes ".inner.fields" and ".name"? I can not find them in the Polars documentation.

@Pain I also tried avoiding the loop, but found no way around it. At least a little consolation can be found in the fact, that you can also access the schema of pl.LazyFrames. Especially, the solution is still valid. The .inner.fields and .name attributes of the pl.Struct and pl.Field datatypes, I found by manually inspecting the object's attributes (using .__dir__).

@Pain I just noticed that jqurious' answer below fully avoids iteration.

struct.field("field_name") extracts specific fields, so you can use field_name instead of * to achieve the result.
result = df.select([
    pl.col("column_0").list.eval(pl.element().struct.field("field_1")).alias("field_1"),
    pl.col("column_0").list.eval(pl.element().struct.field("field_2")).alias("field_2"),
])

In case if you have more fields like field_2, then you can use a generalized function,
def split_struct_column(df: pl.DataFrame, col_name: str) -> pl.DataFrame:
    first_struct = df[col_name].to_list()[0][0]
    field_names = list(first_struct.keys())

    exprs = [
        pl.col(col_name).list.eval(pl.element().struct.field(field)).alias(field)
        for field in field_names
    ]

    return df.select(exprs)


result = split_struct_column(df, "column_0")

I am getting the below output,
┌────────────┬───────────┐
│ field_1    ┆ field_2   │
│ ---        ┆ ---       │
│ list[str]  ┆ list[i64] │
╞════════════╪═══════════╡
│ ["a", "b"] ┆ [1, 2]    │
│ ["c"]      ┆ [3]       │
└────────────┴───────────┘

